# How to get all calender lists

Tags: list

```
web.get_lists(); to get all list but i only want one type of lists
```

Using this gets all the lists, but if i only want to get list of type "Calender" or something else how do i do then?

UPDATE

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    getListCalender = document.getElementById('CalenderListDrop').value;
    spHostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    parentContext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, spHostUrl);
    web = parentContext.get_web();

    var allLists = web.get_lists();

    context.load(allLists);

    context.executeQueryAsync(
            function() {

                var listEnumerator = allLists.getEnumerator();
                while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var listName = listEnumerator.get_current();


                        alert(listName.get_title());




                }

            }),
        function(sender, args) {
            alert(args.get_message());

        }
}
```

);

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SP.List.baseTemplate property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246143(v=office.15).aspx) to determine list definition type on which the list is based. [ListTemplateType enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listtemplatetype) specifies list server templates.

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve lists and filter by `SP.List.baseTemplate`:

```
function getListsByType(typeId,success,error)
{
   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web();
   var lists = web.get_lists()
   context.load(lists);

   context.executeQueryAsync(
     function() {
         var listsResult = [];
         for(var i = 0;i < lists.get_count();i++){
              var list = lists.getItemAtIndex(i);
              var listTypeId = list.get_baseTemplate();
              if(listTypeId == typeId) {
                  listsResult.push(list);
              }
         }
         success(listsResult);
     },
     error);  
}
```

Usage: get calendar lists

```
getListsByType(SP.ListTemplateType.events,
function(lists){
    console.log(String.format('Calendar lists count: {0}',lists.length));
},
function(sender,args)
{
    console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

Key points:

- `SP.ListTemplateType.events (106)` is used to filter only Calendar lists
  lists

**Update**

Changes for your example:

Replace the code after the line: `context.load(allLists);` with this one:

```
context.executeQueryAsync(
   function() {
        for(var i = 0;i < allLists.get_count();i++){
              var list = allLists.getItemAtIndex(i);
              var listTypeId = list.get_baseTemplate();
              if(listTypeId == SP.ListTemplateType.events) {
                  console.log(list.get_title());
              }
         }  
    },
    function(sender, args) {
        //Error handling goes here...
    });
```

Comment: I will update my code in the top, how should i add template type to my existing code

Comment: Hi, the answer has been updated (see Update section)

Comment: Alright thanks, i figured out it by my self in the end, i have one more question in my default.aspx i have this control how do i make so the list are displayed in here <select id="CalenderListDrop">      
      <option></option>
</select> this i the component in my js file  getListCalender = document.getElementById('CalenderListDrop').value;

Comment: Please post a separate question for this..

Comment: I have posted a new question now.